# Writing a batch script to swith between connecting through a proxy server or not

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, proxy

When at work I have to connect to a proxy server and at home there is no server, so every morning I have to go through the fairly tedious routine of ticking the box in Control panel --> Configure proxy settings --> LAN settings (as indicated in the picture)

[image]

Is it possible to write a batch script that will automatically tick or untick this box every time you run it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Windows 7, how to change proxy settings from command line?](http://superuser.com/questions/419696/in-windows-7-how-to-change-proxy-settings-from-command-line)

Comment: Note that while the duplicate question/answer does what you ask for, an alternative you might consider is using a PAC (proxy-auto-config) script. That may be more elegant in some cases.

Comment: Bob's right, see http://superuser.com/q/412374/52492